Output is X when 1, but correct as zero
I'm trying to play "Happy Birthday" using the Basys3.
For some reason the simulation value of the output is X instead of 1:

The outputs are:

clk_440

sound

sound_tb


Each of a different module.
Based on the image above and other observations, I'm pretty sure the system is working as planned except for the mentioned problem.
I also noticed that clk_440 is having the discussed problem but r_clk_440 doesn't. So I ran a simulation only for the clock module and the results were fine as shown:

Meaning, that the problem is somewhere with the main module to my understanding. However, I didn't manage to find it.
Code used from simulation in Image1:
top module:
module main(
    input clk,
    output sound
    );
    
    parameter BEAT=400_000;
    reg [4:0]note_num=0;
    reg en_a=0;
    reg [25:0]timer=0;
    reg r_sound=0;
    
    assign sound=r_sound;
    
    a_clk a_sound(.clk(clk), .en(en_a), .clk_440(sound));
    
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        case (note_num)
            5'd0: begin
                if (timer==BEAT/2) begin
                    timer<=0;
                    en_a<=0;
                    note_num<=5'd1; end
                else begin
                    en_a<=1;
                    timer<=timer+1;
                    note_num<=5'd0; end
            end
   endcase
end
endmodule

a_clk module:
module a_clk(
    input clk,
    input en,
    output clk_440
    );
    
    reg [16:0]counter=0;
    reg r_clk_440=0;
    
    assign clk_440=r_clk_440;
        
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (en) begin 
            if (counter==113_636) begin
                counter<=0;
                r_clk_440<=~r_clk_440; end
            else
                counter<= counter +1;
        end
        else
            counter<=0;
    end
    
endmodule

TestBench:
module simulation(

    );
    reg clk_tb=0;
    wire tb_sound;
    
    main main_tb(.clk(clk_tb), .sound(sound_tb));
    
    always #5 clk_tb<=~clk_tb;
    
endmodule

TestBench used for Image2:
module simulation(

    );
    reg clk_tb=0, en_tb=0;
    wire clk_440_tb;
    
    a_clk a_clk_tb(clk_tb, en_tb, clk_440_tb);
    
    always #5 clk_tb<=~clk_tb;
    
    initial begin
        #20;
        en_tb<=1;
    end
endmodule


Which output is X when what is 1, and correct as what is zero?

sound is X (unknown) because of contention due to these 2 lines in main:
assign sound=r_sound;

a_clk a_sound(.clk(clk), .en(en_a), .clk_440(sound));

You should not drive sound from these 2 different sources:

The continuous assignment using assign
The a_sound instance output port

Driving from one is fine, but not both.

Thank you. I should've see that. Originally my problem was to connect multiple modules like a_sound to the sound output resulting in the same problem (of X output). I now understand (after a good night sleep) I need to use a mux.
